# Grub boot loader uninstallation

Tags: windows-7, linux, uninstall

The laptop I use is Acer 5733. I've partitioned my HDD as AHCI and IDE modes and installed Red Hat server in AHCI and Windows 7 in IDE. Now I want to remove Red Hat, how do I do this?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in several ways:

**With the Windows XP installation CD**

Boot your computer from a Windows XP installation CD and choose `R` for restore or repair. Then you get a terminal with a menu. Choose the number of the Windows partition, typically `1` for `c:\windows` , and type
 the administrator password.

Install NTLoader with the following consecutive commands:

```
fixboot C: fixmbr
```

Done! You should be able to reboot into Windows.

**With the Windows 7 installation DVD**

In Windows 7 the procedure is somewhat different from Windows XP.
Namely as follows:
a. Put the Windows 7 installation disc in the DVD drive and reboot the computer.
b. Press a key when asked to (spacebar is always safe)
c. Choose your language and keyboard, and press Next.
d. Click Repair your computer.
e. Click on the operating system that you would like to "repair" and then click Next.
f. In the System Restore Options, click Command Prompt.
g. Type: `Bootrec.exe /FixBoot` Press Enter.(Note: there is a space between exe and / )
h. Then type:  `Bootrec.exe /FixMbr`  Press Enter.(Note: there is a space between exe and / )
Done! You should be able to reboot into Windows.

**With the free Ultimate Boot CD**
**With an USB memory stick**

And instructions for USB you can find on this [tutorial](https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/grub)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to follow [this tutorial](http://windows7forums.com/windows-7-support/34709-how-remove-grub-loader-get-windows-7-boot-loader-back-uninstalling-linux.html). After you are done and in Windows:

1. Go to `Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Computer Management` and then to `Storage > Disk Management`
2. Choose the HDD with Red Hat's partition.
3. At the bottom of the window you will the drive divided into some partition. Right click on the partition of Red Hat and click `Format..`, and follow the on-screen instructions.
4. After you are done formatting (it may couple of minutes), an *allocated space* will appear where the partition was.
5. Choose the active (Windows 7's) partition, right click on it and choose `Extend Volume..`. Follow the on-screen instructions & extend the volume to the maximum space available.

**Make sure not to format the system partitions / Windows's partition!**